# Do 0-10V proportional valves and dampers require a sourcing or sinking controller?

Tags: hvac

A 0-10V controller can use either sourcing or sinking to set the control voltage ([see Wikipedia 0-10V Lighting Control, for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0-10_V_lighting_control)).  For sinking control, the controlled device provides a high impedance voltage that the controller sinks current from to generate the desired control voltage.  For sourcing control, the controller provides a low impedance voltage to drive a high impedance input on the controller.

**What type of 0-10V control do HVAC proportional valves and dampers use, sourcing or sinking?**

This is a datasheet for a proportional valve: [Siemens SSA61](https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download?10766)

This is a datasheet for a damper actuator: [Johnson Controls EDA-8102](http://vikingcontrols.com/_documents/product/8102PKG.PDF)

Comment: Most likely >= 10k load

Comment: Give a link to the data sheets for the HVAC controls that you might want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Siemens datasheet, under the section "Function / Mechanical Design" at p.3:

> When the actuator is driven by DC 0…10 V control voltage or by a 3-position signal, it
>   produces a stroke which is transmitted to the valve stem.

From the same document, under the section "TECHNICAL DATA" at p.7 (Thanks to Bruce Abbott for pointing out):

> Input impedance for DC 0...10 V is > 100kOhm

Looks like it's most likely sourcing method. This might apply to only Siemens, I don't know. Or maybe it's a standardized or a common method for all.

Comment: from the datasheet "Input impedance for DC 0...10 V > 100 kOhm" - so definitely 'sourcing' (voltage) method.

Comment: @BruceAbbott thanks. Editing my answer.

Comment: The Johnson device has several different operating modes, and can be configured to follow a potentiometer, so with a resistor to the +15 output can source (and can operate from a 1V signal too...)